Sending multiple requests in parallel from a MassTransit state machine
I would like to send multiple requests in parallel. For example, I need to validate two foreign keys, each handled by a different microservice. I want to perform this validation in parallel within a single state instead of sequentially one by one.
Initially(
    When(RequestReceived)
        .Request(this.ValidateModelOne, async context => new 
        {            
            MemberId = "123"
        })
        .Request(this.ValidateModelTwo, async context => new 
        {
            CallId = "456"
        })
        .TransitionTo(Validation)


That is completely valid, no reason why you couldn't or shouldn't.
